# Why is $\sqrt r \cos \frac \theta 2$ harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, polar-coordinates, harmonic-functions

Why is $\sqrt r \cos \frac \theta 2$ harmonic?

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{r}\cos \frac{\theta}{2}=Re(\sqrt{re^{i\theta}})=Re(\sqrt z)$$
The components of analytical functions are harmonic, so this is it.

Comment: I had to make a minor edit to your post in order to cancel a mistaken downvote. Apologies for the annoyance.

Comment: Yes, but where is it harmonic?

Comment: And what square root function is it?

Comment: We know it's harmonic because it's a well known fact that all analytical complex functions of a complex argument ($z$ in this case) satisfy the equation $\nabla^2 Re(f)=\nabla^2 Im(f)=0$, which can be proven using Cauchy-Riemann equations. It doesn't matter which branch of the square root function we're looking at (that actually depends on the range of $\theta$ - (0,2pi) or (-pi,pi) or whatever). You can look at both branches actually, the entire Riemann surface. The fact that it has a local analytical structure is proof enough.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that, in polar coordinates, the Laplacian looks like

$$\Delta = \frac {\partial^2} {\partial r^2} + \frac 1 r \frac \partial {\partial r} + \frac 1 {r^2} \frac {\partial^2} {\partial \theta^2}$$

and that "harmonic" means $\Delta f = 0$, it easy to check that in your case

$$\Delta f = - \frac 1 4 r^{-\frac 3 2} \cos \frac \theta 2 + \frac 1 r \left( \frac 1 2 r^{-\frac 1 2} \cos \frac \theta 2 \right) + \frac 1 {r^2} \left( -\frac 1 4 r^{\frac 1 2} \cos \frac \theta 2 \right) = 0 .$$

Unlike the approach based upon finding an analytic function such that $f$ should be its real or imaginary part, the approach based upon computing the Laplacian has the advantage of not depending on "inspiration", being purely computational (and thus algorithmic).

Comment: This is OK but I don't think this computation is illuminating. It's a purely mechanical procedure. However, identifying it as the real part of a holomorphic function can be instructive. It shows you where the problem came from. Also, where exactly do you think f is harmonic, on the basis of your computation?

Comment: @zhw.: $f$ is harmonic there where polar coordinates may exist (in the differentiable sense). My approach is better because harmonic functions exist in arbitrary many dimensions, while analytic functions are usually considered only in 2 dimensions. This shows that the underpinnings of harmonicity are not analytic, but merely Riemannian (try to define harmonic forms as in Hodge theory using analyticity - you won't be able to do it).